# instantiating an interface like Set in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently working with the Kotlin programming language.
When it came to the topic of collections, I came across “sets” and something caught my eye.

By definition, Set is an interface

```
public interface Set<out E> : Collection<E> {
    // Query Operations

    override val size: Int
    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean
    override fun contains(element: @UnsafeVariance E): Boolean
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<E>

    // Bulk Operations
    override fun containsAll(elements: Collection<@UnsafeVariance E>): Boolean
}
```

The function "setOf()" returns also an instance of "Set", maybe it is a builderFunction (I can't find a implementation). Then why can I create an instance of such a set interface even though it is actually not possible to create instances of an interface?

Comment: Try some code to see what classes it uses from you create a Set. https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS45LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihzZXRPZjxBbnk+KCk6OmNsYXNzLnNpbXBsZU5hbWUpXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihzZXRPZjxBbnk+KFwiXCIpOjpjbGFzcy5zaW1wbGVOYW1lKVxuICAgIHByaW50bG4oc2V0T2Y8QW55PigxLCAyKTo6Y2xhc3Muc2ltcGxlTmFtZSlcbn0ifQ==

Comment: It's actually creating an instance of a concrete class implementing that interface.